# Kivy get name/text from clicked ListItemButton

Tags: python, kivy

i have a question about dynamic listview in python with kivy. So the listview is working, but know i want to get the text from the clicked listview item, to push them to the python file. But i can't finde any solution that works for me. I think one way to do this is with "on_selection_change" but i'm not able to get this run. 
So here is my code

```
BoxLayout:
    pos: 130,10
    size: 500,400
    ListView:
        adapter:
            ListAdapter(data=root.my_data,
            args_converter=lambda row_index, an_obj: {'text': an_obj,'size_hint_y': 28,'height': 40, 'font_size': 20},
            selection_mode='single',
            allow_empty_selection=True,
            cls=ListItemButton)
<ListItemButton>:
#on_selection_change=self.on_selection_change
on_release: app.getname()
```

and my python file

```
class PCScreen(GridLayout,Screen):
    filename = open("/home/pi/Documents/ppcont/config/name.txt")
    my_data = ListProperty(filename)

def getname(self):
    pass
```

Comment: provide a [mcve]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As for ListView, use *ModalView* to control selection and invoke *getname()* method. Please refer to the two examples (ListView and RecycleView) for details.

## Note

[ListView](https://kivy.org/docs/api-kivy.uix.listview.html) has been deprecated since version 1.10.0, use [RecycleView](https://kivy.org/docs/api-kivy.uix.recycleview.html) instead.

## Example 1 - ListView

### mainlistview.py

```
from kivy.app import App
from kivy.uix.modalview import ModalView
from kivy.properties import ObjectProperty


class MyListView(ModalView):
    list_view = ObjectProperty(None)

    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        super(MyListView, self).__init__(**kwargs)
        self.list_view.adapter.bind(on_selection_change=self.callback_function)

    def callback_function(self, instance):
        print(instance)
        App.get_running_app().getname()


class MainListViewApp(App):
    title = "ListView ListItemButton Demo"

    def build(self):
        return MyListView()

    def getname(self):
        print("App.getname() - Called")


if __name__ == '__main__':
    MainListViewApp().run()
```

### mainlistview.kv

```
#:kivy 1.10.0
#:import lv kivy.uix.listview
#:import la kivy.adapters.listadapter

<MyListView>:
    list_view: list_view
    ListView:
        id: list_view
        adapter:
            la.ListAdapter(
            data=["Item #{0}".format(i) for i in range(100)],
            selection_mode='single',
            allow_empty_selection=True,
            cls=lv.ListItemButton)
```

### Output - ListView

[image]

## Example 2 - RecycleView

### mainrecycleview.py

```
from kivy.app import App
from kivy.uix.recycleview import RecycleView
from kivy.uix.recycleview.views import RecycleDataViewBehavior
from kivy.uix.button import Button
from kivy.uix.recycleboxlayout import RecycleBoxLayout
from kivy.uix.behaviors import FocusBehavior
from kivy.uix.recycleview.layout import LayoutSelectionBehavior
from kivy.properties import ObjectProperty


class SelectableRecycleBoxLayout(FocusBehavior, LayoutSelectionBehavior, RecycleBoxLayout):
    """ Adds selection and focus behaviour to the view. """
    pass


class SelectableButton(RecycleDataViewBehavior, Button):
    """ Add selection support to the Label """
    index = None

    def refresh_view_attrs(self, rv, index, data):
        """ Catch and handle the view changes """
        self.index = index
        return super(SelectableButton, self).refresh_view_attrs(rv, index, data)

    def on_release(self):
        print("Pressed & released on", self.text)
        App.get_running_app().getname()


class RV(RecycleView):
    rv_layout = ObjectProperty(None)

    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        super(RV, self).__init__(**kwargs)
        self.data = [{'text': "Button " + str(x), 'id': str(x)} for x in range(100)]


class MainRecycleViewApp(App):
    title = "RecycleView Button Demo"

    def build(self):
        return RV()

    def getname(self):
        print("RecycleView: App.getname() - Called")


if __name__ == "__main__":
    MainRecycleViewApp().run()
```

### mainrecycleview.kv

```
#:kivy 1.10.0

<SelectableButton>:
    # Draw a background to indicate selection
    canvas.before:
        Color:
            rgba: (0.0, 0.9, 0.1, 0.3)
        Rectangle:
            pos: self.pos
            size: self.size

<RV>:
    rv_layout: layout
    viewclass: 'SelectableButton'
    SelectableRecycleBoxLayout:
        id: layout
        default_size: None, dp(26)
        default_size_hint: 1, None
        size_hint_y: None
        height: self.minimum_height
        orientation: "vertical"
```

### Output - RecycleView

[image: Img02 - RecycleView]

Answer (score 0):

I really think you should dump `ListView`, its deprecated (from the docs):

```
ListAdapter:
 Module: kivy.adapters.listadapter Added in 1.5
Deprecated since version 1.10.0: The feature has been deprecated.
```

you should really use https://kivy.org/docs/api-kivy.uix.recycleview.html